# Spark reading from a new location keeping the output directory same

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark job which reads (using structured streaming API) from a source s3://bucket/source-1 folder and writes to s3://bucket/destination-1 folder. The checkpoints are saved at s3://bucket/checkpoint-1.

Now I want to read the data with the same schema from s3://bucket/source-2 (with checkpointing at s3://bucket/checkpoint-2) but i want to append it to the same s3://bucket/destination-2 folder. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course this is possible to write into the same location.  But there are different things that you need to take into account, like:

- what data format you're using as output (Parquet, Delta, something else...)?
- are these both streaming jobs are running in the same time? Could you have conflicts when writing data?
- (potentially) what is partitioning schema for the destination?

Comment: I am using parquet. There is no conflict actually. This is the change in the source so it's just one time change. What is happening currently is new checkpoint and new source start from batch0 and while writing spark_metadata realises there are already batch0, 1 ...and discards them.